# How to get exactly the same list of "Parameters used" shown in the All Executions Overview report by using T-SQL from SSISDB database?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis, ssms

Is it possible to get exactly the same parameters as shown in the **All execution Overview report** (see the printscreen below)?

[image]

I was trying to use the table **[internal].[execution_parameter_values]** from SSISDB and filter it via **execution_id**, nevertheless it returns much more parameters than in the report. I have also tried to filter it with table attribute "value_set", "object_type", etc. but still it did not return the same list as in the report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overview report in the SSIS catalog shows only TOP 25 used parameters sorted by `parameter_name` ASC.

Also, it is needed to filter out the records with parameter_name without "." character.

So the result T-SQL script would be:

```
SELECT TOP 25 
      [parameter_name]
      ,[parameter_value]
      ,[parameter_data_type]
  FROM [SSISDB].[internal].[execution_parameter_values]
  WHERE execution_id = @execution_id AND parameter_name not like '%.%'
  ORDER BY parameter_name
```

Answer (score 1):

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-views/views-integration-services-catalog?view=sql-server-2017

> **execution_parameter_value**:
>   Displays the actual parameter values that
>   are used by Integration Services packages during an instance of
>   execution.

Whenever the package is executed, records are inserted into that table.  You need to determine the execution_id that you want to filter on.

You can get that from [catalog].[executions] in the SSIS DB.  Filter based on your project or package and when it was executed.

Or you will also see that in the execution overview report as "Operation ID":
[image]

You can then filter based on that value:

```
    SELECT * FROM [internal].[execution_parameter_values]
    WHERE [execution_id] = 16529
```

Comment: Sorry that I did not write it down during my question. Of course I was trying to filter [execution_parameter_values] by execution_id, but the problem is that it still returns much more data that is in the report. I will update my question to be completely sure.